# More compact RegEx for capturing one or more groups with delimiters - without repeating the group expression

Tags: regex, delimiter

This occurs so frequently in validation RegExps I was wondering whether there was a more efficient form that I'm missing.

Consider the following RegExp: `^[\w\s-&’'!À-Üà-øoù-ÿŒœ]+(\|[\w\s-&’'!À-Üà-øoù-ÿŒœ]+)*$`

All it's doing is validating all of the following:

- l'écureuil
- losange|l'hibou|Œdeppe

What is frustrating me is that I must repeat the entire capture class twice, just so I can handle the cases of a single entry (with no leading delimiter), and then cases where there are multiple groups separated by the (required) delimiter

`\1` doesn't work here of course because I'm not matching *the same* string.

(this question is not about how I can capture French words using a more succinct class definition - that's just an arbitrary example)

Comment: Use [subroutines](https://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html).

Comment: Note that the `|` in your expression does not match an actual `|` character. `|` in regex means "or".

Comment: Thanks @Jerry- edited.

Comment: The duplicated question ist a working, but my Idea was to only Check, If The First character is a delimiter Like `^[^\|]([\|\w\s-&’'!À-Üà-øoù-ÿŒœ]+)*$`